# Exclude certain directory from RewriteEngine on a Server running TYPO3

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, typo3

I want to develop a new website for a customer who is currently running a TYPO3 website on his server.

I'd like to exclude a subdirectory from the TYPO3 RewriteEngine (realurl?) so I have normal access to that subdirectory.

> www.domain.com/dev

for example.

I have access to that site but as soon as I put a .htaccess file in that certain directory to protect it with a htpasswd. I get a TYPO3 Error:

> Reason: Segment "dev" was not a keyword for a postVarSet as expected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and it was anything but straightforward.

I needed to add this line to my .htaccess in the protected subdirectory:

```
ErrorDocument 401 "Not authorized"
```

Apparently there is a conflict between URL rewriting and Basic Auths in cases just like mine. The Server writes a "401 Unauthorized" Header and looks for an existing error document based on a pre-defined path which then gets rewritten.

Answer (score 1):

In .htaccess find this

```
# Stop rewrite processing, if we are in the typo3/ directory or any other known directory
# NOTE: Add your additional local storages here
RewriteRule (?:typo3/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]
```

and add your directory there

```
# Stop rewrite processing, if we are in the typo3/ directory or any other known directory
# NOTE: Add your additional local storages here
RewriteRule (?:typo3/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico|dev/) - [L]
```

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately it still won't work as soon as I add this .htaccess into the dev directory:

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
Require valid-user

Without this .htaccess it works just fine.

Comment: You have to put this .htaccess rules in web root.